# Unable to svn rebase after doing git lfs migrate

Tags: git, svn, git-lfs

I've been migrating a Subversion codebase to Git.  All went well and I `git svn clone(d)` the repo and then `git lfs migrate(d)` the large and binary files.  The repo looks fine from the Git side but I now cannot `git svn rebase`...

`$ git svn rebase
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
$`

I've tried various suggestions from the web on solving this problem but they seem to have no effect.  Any suggestions?  Can I reset the Subversion/Git info?  Should I have `git lfs install(ed)` before doing the `git lfs clone`?

Comment: I'm slowly coming to the conclusion that it is not possible to use both `git svn` and `git lfs`. What I see is that if I install `git lfs` then this is ignored when I do a `git svn fetch/clone` meaning all large files are still committed to `git` directly.  If I try to do a `git lfs import` afterwards, the `git svn` indexing is broken and I can no longer keep in step with the Subversion repo.  My next step is to see if a two-step process might be possible so Subversion => Git (normal) => Git (LFS).

Comment: My experiments with Subversion => Git (normal) => Git (LFS) did not go well.  The Git => Git step fails with errors complaining because the files that should be LFS.ed are not in the Git (normal) repo using LFS and the `git pull` from the Normal to LFS repos fails.  Starting to feel like I will have to do some sort of sparse checkout of 'all files changed by commit X' and then apply them to the LFS repo, and somehow maintain commit info!

Answer (score 0):

The reason `git svn` indexing is broken when using `git lfs import` is that the later rewrites the Git repository history (unless the [`--no-rewrite`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn#import-no-rewrite) option is given).

If using the `--no-rewrite` option is viable to you (that is: you can handle keeping the big files in the Git repository history, only removing them from future commits), then maybe it's the easiest way to go.

On the other hand, if you must keep those large binary files away from your repository storage entirely, there must be no commit in its history that adds those files directly to Git. Therefore, you must keep using the plain `git lfs import` to rewrite all the commits created by `git svn clone/fetch` and redirect those files to the LFS. After running the `git lfs import`, you will need to regenerate the git-svn `rev_map` to map the new commits in the rewritten Git history to the SVN revisions they mirror. I don't know if there is an easy way to do this, but you may have a look at the code in https://github.com/Eloston/git-svn-lfs to have an idea.